Microsoft Word: sub-bullets without increasing the indent level
I couldn't find a way to obtain a very simple result and I couldn't find answers addressing this specific need, that is including sub-bullets like "3a" and "3b" but at the same hierarchical level (and indentation) of the previous/following numbers, like in this example that I made up editing the image:

The automatic numbering system rejects my attempts to customize a number, so I can only obtain a similar result making everything by hand, numbering and adjusting the indentation one item at a time. Is there a better workflow allowed within Word?
Thank you

What you may be wanting is to have these at the same outline level.

Define a style with the correct formatting, indent, and hierarchy level, but without any numbering. Then, type control-F9 SEQ num in front of every paragraph (you can copy/paste this). This will generate a number, same as with automatic numbered lists.
For the sub-paragraphs with -a, just add the -a manually; for any further sub-paragraphs, do the same but also use control-F9 SEQ \c num instead of the above. This gives you the previous number instead of a new one.
Finally, select everything and hit F9.
If you show fields (Alt-F9) you'll see this:

And without showing fields (Alt-F9again):

You can add symbols, including a TAB character, inside the field if you want to align your sentences. Here is an example:


Note that the space before the second double quote is actually a Tab.
Also, I had to take the -a, -b etc. inside the formatting to get the alignment this way (and the minus won't show, as it is a reserved character).

I think this is very close to what I'm trying to do, yet I'm not getting the numbers as real "indices" of each paragraph, they turn out to be the first characters of the paragraph itself. Am I mistaking something? (you say "in fron of every paragraph, but I'm not allowed to write before the paragraph itself) Is this a necessary compromise?

Not sure I understand you correctly, I'll add some pictures to clarify

Thanks, your image confirms my suspect. So I've updated my post including a (photo-edited) picture as well, to show exactly what I'm trying to obtain about automatic indentation levels

Added some more, if this is not what you meant then you'll have to explain a bit more...

It works, thank you! I removed the dashes altogether since I prefer "3a" and I added \c as per your first example, to get "3b" instead of 4... voilà, 100% what I was trying to achieve!
